# Crankset identification

Tags: crankset, drivetrain, bike-friday

Does anyone know, which exact crankset is pictured below? It came shipped with a Bike Friday NWT (New World Tourist)

[image]

Comment: Can you give a better photo of the wording on the crank arm ?    Another option if it came shipped new with that crankset is to ask the seller/retailer directly.

Comment: It's a Origin8 Alloy Single / Double Crankset.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: I want to replace a crank arm which is bend since it's been hit by a car. I can only find dealers in the US which makes shipping quire expensive and I guess as of know ... Corona ... unvertain in terms of how long it will take. I therefore decided to get a completly new crank arm set.

Comment: You should be able to find a replacement crank arm without too much trouble (far less trouble than replacing the entire crankset).  The two biggest questions are what is the bolt circle diameter (fairly easy to measure), and what sort of shaft is it -- square taper or octalink.  You *might* be able to tell this by looking at the back side of the crank arm.  Note that it is a "self pulling" crank -- you don't need a crank puller to remove it, just unscrew the center bolt.  (BTW, you also need the crank arm length, but that's fairly obvious.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where can you buy single crank arms? Almost every store has square taper cranksets but I know only one dealer that has single arms and they're specializing in surplus NOS.

Comment: [This](https://www.modernbike.com/origin8-alloy-crank-set-175mm-110x5-bolt-silver) appears to be a single crank arm ...

Comment: Interesting. Looks like they have lots of unusual length cranks and unusual spare parts too.

Comment: @ojs - I suspect that normally you'd have to buy the pair, but that's no biggie, compared to buying and installing an entire crankset (especially since there are about a dozen different "standards" for cranksets).

Comment: I still don't get how finding out the standard for single crank would be easier than for a full set, how replacing both would be significantly more difficult than replacing one or how maintaining SKUs for independent cranks in addition to sets for all length, standards, models, etc would be easier to vendors. But I guess our thought processes are different.

Answer (score 3):

The logo is for brand Origin8. It is not a current production model listed on their web site, but you search search for "origin8 crank", you'll find similar looking cranksets sold simply as "Origin8 alloy crankset".

Answer (score 0):

Well its not stock - it looks vaguely BMX-like to me.   I do notice that it is wearing the stock BikeFriday pedals though.

That model of bike looks like this new:

[image: From Bike Friday website.]

A zoom of the crankset shows a triple:

[image]

Though other bikes in their range come with single and double chainring options too, none look like your single chainring.

---

I've also searched the catalogue at https://www.bikefriday.com/userfiles/Bike.Friday.Catalog.Silk.pdf  and no BF bike has that crankset.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! The question has been answered in the Bikefriday Facebook group. It's an Origin8 Alloy Single / Double Crankset.